# How to Get all RequiredFieldValidator in a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

How can I get all requiredfieldvalidator in a page and Change its errormessage?

I tried using the code below but it change all validators including regularexpressionvalidator.

```
private void GetValidator()
{
    foreach (IValidator cValidator in Page.GetValidators(null))
    {
        BaseValidator bv = (cValidator as BaseValidator);
        bv.CssClass = "Error";
        bv.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
        bv.Text = "* Error Message!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code like below, where the validators collection is obtained through `Page.Validators` property of Page object. And also, you will need to check if the validator in loop is a `RequiredFieldValidator` or not using the if statement in snippet below.

```
foreach (IValidator validator in Page.Validators)
{

    BaseValidator bv = (validator as BaseValidator);
    //check if validator is a RequiredFieldValidator
    if(bv is RequiredFieldValidator) {
      bv.CssClass = "Error";
      bv.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
      bv.Text = "* Error Message!";
    }
}
```

If you use `Page.GetValidators(null)` then it gives you the validators only for default validation group i.e. all validators which have no validation group specified. This would exclude validators that have a validation group assigned.